# Bootstrap Toggle to Change MySQL TINYINT Without Page Refresh Using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

in my application I would like to change a boolean state held in my MySQL db as a TINYINT [0,1] by changing the state of a checkbox styled as a toggle by using the [bootstrap toggle plugin](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/).  Wow... that's a mouthful.

The trick is that I want the TINYINT to update in the background with no page refresh visible.  I have been trying to figure this out via AJAX.  I can check the state of the toggle and can console.log the state change, but I cannot get the AJAX section to actually execute the POST to my toggle_track.php page which will update the db.  I'm open to any ideas and willing to try almost anything.

Now, for the code examples:

**main.php**

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="On" data-off="Off">
<div id="console-event"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
      console.log('state checked: ' + $(this).prop('checked'));

      if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var visible = 1;
      } else {
        var visible = 0;
      }
      console.log('variable checked: ' + visible);

      var xhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      console.log('browsers checked: ' + xhttp);

// xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
//   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
//     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
//   }
// };

     xhttp.open("POST","../private/dynamic/toggle_track.php?visible="+visible,true);
     console.log('Open: ' + xhttp.open);

     xhttp.send();

     console.log('POST run');
   })
  })
</script>
```

**toggle_track.php**

```
<?php

  require_once('../initialize.php');

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.alert('made it');
</script>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['visible'])) {


$incident['visible'] = $_POST['visible'];

  $incident_id = $_SESSION['incident_id'];

  // update the entire associative array in the db.
  $result = update_incident($incident_id);
  if($result === true) {    // Check to see if the UPDATE was successful.
    // Yes, the UPDATE was successful.
    // load a message to be displayed.
    // $step_updated = 'Incident: ' . $incident['id'] . ' was updated.  Step #' . $step['id'] . ' was added.  The array should now show: ' . $sa_load;
    // $ans_updated = ' and the answer for #' . $step['id'] . ' was added.  The array should now show: ' . $ans_load;
  }
    // No, the UPDATE failed.
    else {
    // load message to show what failed.
    $errors = $result;
  }  // end else

}


 ?>
```

**query_functions.php**
after making connection with the database in the `require_once('../initialize.php');` statement above:

```
function update_incident($incident) {
global $db;

$sql = "UPDATE incidents SET ";
$sql .= "visible='" . db_escape($db, $incident['visible']) . "', ";
$sql .= "note='" . db_escape($db, $incident['note']) . "', ";
$sql .= "resolved='" . db_escape($db, $incident['resolved']) . "', ";
$sql .= "step_array='" . db_escape($db, $incident['step_array']) . "',";
$sql .= "ans_array='" . db_escape($db, $incident['ans_array']) . "',";
$sql .= "lastStep='" . db_escape($db, $incident['lastStep']) . "',";
$sql .= "valid='" . db_escape($db, $incident['valid']) . "' ";
$sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $incident['id']) . "' ";
$sql .= "LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
// For UPDATE statements, $result is true/false
if($result){
  return true;
} else {
  //UPDATE failed
  echo mysqli_error($db);
  db_disconnect($db);
  exit;
}
}
```

I hope this code segment explains my thinking enough to help derive an answer.

Comment: You have this tagged as `jquery`, so why not just use [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of all that `XMLHttpRequest` nonsense?

Comment: Was borrowing from W3Schools AJAX tutorials.  I'd love to use those two methods, but apparently I seem to be missing the information to do so.  Got any ideas?

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time and frustration and stop using w3schcools.  They are widely regarded as having poor, outdated, and even just plain wrong information. Refer to official documentation whenever possible (such as the links in my previous comment), use the many, _many_ examples already here on SO, and, if needed, yes, sometimes even _paid_, reputable courses/tutorials/webinars/etc.

Comment: Thanks for that Patrick Q.  Actually, I use a combination of all of those.  Especially with the paid courses [Lynda.com & Udemy].  Lately I had been hitting a roadblock and decided to ask a question here on SO rather than sifting through other solutions which weren't quite working [I tried about a dozen].

Comment: Okay, so can you try to clarify where exactly your problem is?  You say "but I cannot get the AJAX section to actually execute the POST to my toggle_track.php page", so does that mean that you have checked your browser's network tab and seen that there is no request made when you hit the toggle?  You have a number of `console.log` statements in there, so that's good.  What do they produce? Do you hit the "browsers checked" one? What about the "Open:" one?  "POST run"?

Comment: Yes, all of my console.log statements execute.  I would expect that when the POST is made to the toggle_track.php page that the script on that page calling for an alert should execute.  Because I don't get that alert and my db does not update, I assume that my POST is actually failing.  Does that make sense?  Am I oversimplifying my expectation?

Comment: Well, first, you're skipping the first debugging step of checking your network tab to see if the request is being sent at all. If it is, then check that the values passed are what you expect, and then check what it shows at the response. Second, you're misunderstanding how ajax works. The Javascript on toggle_track.php is not going to execute, it is simply going to be returned as text as part of the response. You should probably also check your apache/PHP error logs, as you might be getting some errors there.

Comment: Hey Patrick... you might add your last suggestion as an answer so that I can mark this as solved.  Directing me to the error logs took me to the root of my problem: **Javascript Type Casting**.  I was setting the variable to a 0 or 1 and trying to load that to my db.  It was interpreting that as a string 0 or 1 and trying to load it against a db filed looking for a TINYINT.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but I didn't solve the problem, you did, so I wouldn't feel comfortable posting an answer.  You're more than welcome to though, as self-answers are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...many thanks to Patrick Q who put me on the right track.  Here are the edits that made it work:

**main.php**

*I made the following change:*

```
if($(this).prop('checked')) {
  var visible = "true";
} else {
  var visible = "false";
}
```

Then on **toggle_track.php** I made this change:

```
$incident = [];

$raw_visible = $_POST['visible'];

if($raw_visible == "true") {
  $incident['visible'] = 1;
} elseif($raw_visible == "false") {
  $incident['visible'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you don't get your POST on toggle_track.php right? You have the right idea, but I would to this this way:

On **main.php**

```
      //Same code until console.log();

        //Not really needed in this case to be sent in an array, but I kinda like it :P 
        var dataToSend = {
            visible: visible
        };

        //Sending data using jQuery AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: 'toggle_track.php',  //Where to
            type: "POST",  //Method
            data: dataToSend, //The array I created with the "visible" variable
            //A success function, for when the CONNECTION WITH THE URL was succesfull
            success:  function (response) {
                //If COMMUNICATION was successful (Doesn't mean it went all right)
            },
            //An error function, for when the CONNECTION WITH THE URL 
            //wasn't succesfull (couldn't be found, etc)
            error: function(response){
              //If COMMUNICATION had an error
            }
        });
       })
      })
    </script>
```

Sorry if I don't explain myselft correctly, English isn't my first language. I'll try to answer any questions you have.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Your response was right, I'm not getting my POST to toggle_track.php.  I would expect to see an alert box popup confirming that I had made it to the page.  I tried your section of code, but I seem to be hitting the same problem. :/

Comment: If you are trying to get an alert, it needs to be on the "success" or "error" methods of the .ajax() function. Why? Because even if your script is triggered, it isn't in the same file you are currently viewing.

You could make a test. Make a dummy toggle_tracker.php file that:

if (isset($_POST['visible'])){
echo "It's ok";
} else{
echo "Ok";
}

Now, on main.php, on the success or error methods in the ajax function, add a 

console.log(response);

It should print on console what are you getting back, if it is "Ok" then your post is being sent and received ok.